# Tag page with blog layout

Tags: joomla-4.x, articles, overrides, tags

I want to create a menu item for a tag that shows the articles as in category blog layout.
After, I would like to insert tags in the article info block.
Is it possible in joomla 4 and 5?
If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered the Article view options are somewhat limited. If you are not using article categories for anything else you could put all your articles in one category and use that for a category blog view and you can apply a tag filter in the menu item setup.

But you can't select multiple categories for the category blog view which seems a shame as that would enable you to have a blog view  of all categories and filter that by tag (or tags). The same applies to the Category list view which requires a category to be chosen - in fact there doesn't seem to be a way to list all articles across categories in a site view as you can in admin articles view (which seems odd - same applies in J3). So you can't achieve what you want with a simple alternative layout to an existing article model.

Ever since they were introduced the built in tagging view facilities have been sorely lacking. It is disappointing that in J5 they have not been much improved (they are a bit better). A Blog style layout of the items selected for a tag view would be good - but tricky to implement as a tag can be applied to items from different components.

In J3 I ended up developing my own views for tags, and now I'm starting the painful migration to J5 (having missed 4 as it was rubbish) I see that I'm going to have to do the same.

Essentially you need to develop your own tagged items blog view, or a tagged articles blog view if you only want articles, in a custom component.

Regarding showing tags in the article info blog (presumably in a single article view?) that can be achieved with a layout override or some template fettlling.